# Using loc still rises SettingWithCopyWarning Warning while changing column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter URLs form text column of my df by filtering all `http` `https` like below:

```py
data.loc[:,'text_'] = data['text_'].str.replace(r'\s*https?://\S+(\s+|$)', ' ').str.strip()
```

I used the `loc` as advised in other answers but I still keep getting the warning.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
time: 9.81 s (started: 2022-03-19 06:35:42 +00:00)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1773: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_column(ilocs[0], value, pi)
```

How to do this operation correctly ie. without the warning?

UPDATE:

I've generated data from kaggle dataset:

```
kaggle datasets download clmentbisaillon/fake-and-real-news-dataset
```

and then:

```
true_df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
fake_df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
true_df['is_fake'] = 0 
fake_df['is_fake'] = 1
news_df = pd.concat([true_df, fake_df])

news_df = news_df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

```
drop_list = ['subject', 'date']
column_filter = news_df.filter(drop_list) 
news_df.drop(column_filter, axis=1)

news_df['text_'] = news_df['title'] + news_df['text']
```

[image]

```
data = news_df[['text_', 'is_fake']]
```

Next for the following line:

```
data.loc[:,'text_'] = data['text_'].str.replace(r'\s*https?://\S+(\s+|$)', ' ').str.strip()
```

I get that error from the start of the post.

UPDATE 2:
As mentioned by @Riley Adding the

```
data = data.copy()
```

Fix the `SettingWithCopyWarning` however the:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Still remains. To fix it change  `regex=True` fo `replace`:

```
data.loc[:,'text_'] = data['text_'].str.replace(r'\s*https?://\S+(\s+|$)', ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
```

Comment: The issue is prior to this point. How did you generate `data`?

Comment: @mozway I've updated the process of `data` generation. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Why to avoid using `inplace` parameter https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-probably-never-use-pandas-inplace-true-9f9f211849e4

Comment: @Riley I've removed the `inplace=True` but the Warning still remains

Comment: @mCs don't forget to assign the result of the calc to a variable in those lines where you have dropped `inplace`.  Understanding how these warnings are generated can be difficult.  If you want a good understanding keep reading articles like the one I linked until it clicks.  In the meantime you can probably get around it in your code above by throwing in a `data = data.copy()` prior to the line generating the warning.

Comment: @Riley Thanks, I've updated the post. #2 Now it removed first warning but the second `FutureWarning` is still there.